# How to cycle through many threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, concurrency

For our project to develop a network stress test tool, we are flooding packets to entire subnets. We have a Runnable class that takes a port and the broadcast address and in a while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted) loop, it sends a specific packet. We then have a main class that iterates through every network interface and every possible port and adds the Runnable class to an ExecutorService with 1000 thread fixed pool. The issue is that if ExecutorService waits for the current 1000 threads to finish processing, they never will since they are in a while loop. However, starting every single thread (65536 * number of interfaces) would take up too much memory. We are looking for a way to cycle through the threads so they all have an opportunity to operate for some time and conserve memory while still maintaining a high network output.

Comment: i dont think i would want to contribute to this effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be suffering from the misconception that more threads always gives higher throughput. This is often not the case.

Your application is likely going to be CPU bound, or bound by the network card's throughput. Forcing the OS to juggle tens of thousands of threads competing for these resources is *not* going to increase your throughput. High numbers of threads only helps when the threads are spending most of their lives waiting on some high-capacity, external resource (e.g. a database). Since you're just blasting packets and (presumably) not interested in any responses, there is no natural waiting point.

I would recommend you only have as many threads as you have processors and/or network cards (whichever is smaller).

Comment: So it would work just as well to use one thread? I thought that more threads would be faster because when I created a port scanning program which had a timeout period per port, multiple threads sped up the program considerably.

Comment: This could be still very well be multi-threaded, especially since a single thread will progress much slower, blocked waiting for replies from the network.  A single thread is a good consideration (since threads are often misused), but there is still a valid use-case here...

Comment: Are you using TCP packets or unicast? If you're waiting for ACK, multiple thread will provide some benefit. But only to a limit. They very quickly will get in each other's way. Try numbers like 1, 5, 10, 50 and find the sweet spot.

Comment: Also use monitoring tools dstat (linux), perfomon (Windows) and look for CPU, network usage and context switches (roughly, thread switching overhead).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make each thread always run to completion or 'forever', make the threads execute a small, well-defined set of work, then re-add them to the executor.  This high level management can be done by a 'controller' style object that manages re-adding tasks to the executor queue with a new range of steps to execute.

For example, if each task has 1000 steps to execute repeatedly: 
- Task 1 runs steps 1-100, then finishes by adding itself back to the executor queue for steps 101-200
- Task 2 gets a chance to execute (and finish) similarly
- Task 1 is next in the queue now, so it executes 101-200, then adds back to the executor queue for 201-300.
- etc until Task 1 reaches the end - 901-1000 - then if it wants to continue executing, goes back for 1-100 again.

In your case, the different steps may be the ports, with different threads representing the different broadcast addresses - break it up as you see fit.